# The special charcters used in Email subject is not coming properly?How to resolve this issue?

Tags: magento2, multistore, email-templates

We have used few special characters in Email subject for French and German language like **ä, n°.** These letters are converted to **"? ".**

In email subject, How to resolve this issue?

But these are coming correctly in the email body. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont copy those from direct word or emails. Copy to text editor like notepad++, sublime etc then copy the text and paste it to email templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is reported in Magento2 [#8094](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8094)

And here is the [Reference](https://github.com/PieterCappelle/magento2/commit/aa64bf7340162cbba0e854a7604c901f25ca6999) of git commit .

Quick fix is

> di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
    <plugin name="mail_subject" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Template" sortOrder="100" />
</type>
</config>
```

> In Template.php

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin;

class Template
{
    public function afterGetSubject(
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$result, ENT_QUOTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting the same.

Comment: return htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$subject, ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: did you used the above function ?

Comment: <?php 
namespace Test\SpecialCharacter\Plugin;

class Template
{
    public function afterGetSubject(
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template $subject,
        $result
    ) {

       return htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$subject, ENT_QUOTES);
  
    }
}

Comment: I used this but i am not getting mail,First i used $result i was getting mail but with that '"?".But if i use $subject am  not getting the mail.

Comment: Replace your function with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79021/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-dilip).

Comment: not working.
The plugin what i created is it correct.
I have created a module SpecialCharcter inside that
<type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template"> 
<plugin name="mail_subject" type="Test\SpecialCharacter\Plugin\Template" sortOrder="100" /> 
</type>
this is di.xml
and inside Plugin i have created template.php

Comment: Hello @Dilip have you got any solution on this after ?

Comment: No. I have given the subject in English and then put the translations in CSV file.